# ArcGIS Pro Import Symbology From Layer

Tags: symbology, arcgis-pro

In ArcMap; during the Import Symbology function you had the option to import the "Complete Symbology Definition". However, I can not find the option in Pro or any Python script that could solve this problem.

I've read that using the "Apply Symbology From Layer" geoprocessing tool would accomplish the task in Pro if you used a LYRX as the "Symbology Layer". But when I tried this it did not keep the break values constant (which is what I ultimately want).

In other words, if the layer I'm basing the symbology off of looks like this
[image: Symbology]

I want the colors associated with 1-14 to remain constant.

Am I missing something? Is there a solution for this using ArcPy? Or is it just not possible unless ESRI adds the "Complete Symbology Definition" feature into ArcGIS Pro?

Comment: When you say "it still did not work", what was the [code snippet](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) that you ran, and what were the errors that resulted?

Comment: This appears to have been discussed on the ESRI Forums with no solution.  https://community.esri.com/ideas/12245.  Have you tried to bring in the layer with the symbology you want, and then changing its source to the layer you want to symbolize?  Could you do the work in ArcMap using the complete symbology definition, saving that as a layer file, then opening it in Pro?

Comment: I talked to ESRI's Help Desk and they did some testing of their own and determined this to be a software defect, and are working on getting it fixed